# Image Classification using Single Class Dataset using Transfer Learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, transfer-learning

I only have around 1000 images of vehicle. I need to train a model that can identify if the image is vehicle or not-vehicle. I do not have a dataset for not-vehicle, as it could be anything besides vehicle.

I guess the best method for this would be to apply transfer learning. I am trying to train data on a pre-trained VGG19 Model. But still, I am unaware on how to train a model with just vehicle images without any non-vehicle images. I am not being able to classify it.

I am new to ML Overall, Any solution based on practical implementation will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tensorflow Object Detection [API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection).

In the API, you dont have to have 2 or more labels. It can be used with only one label. By transforming images to tfrecords, you can train and predict other images. The prediction will you give you **bounding boxes** and **probabilities** that how much an object identified as a vehicle.

The challenge in here is labeling object locations on the images. **[LabelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg)** is a great tool for that.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If creating classifier for your images is your final goal then you can simple get some images for non vehicles.

Either download image dataset like Imagenet, CIFAR etc and sample images that are non-vehicle like dogs, flower etc. Just make sure to include sufficient variety of classes and around 1000 images.

Or you can source data directly from internet eg. using web crawlers

I recommend sampling from existing dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using pretrained model and take the output. You might need to apply dimensionality reduction e.g. PCA, to get a more managable size input. After that you can train novelty detection model to identify whether the output is different than your training set.

Another method would be using autoencoder. So the idea is if the tested image is "similar" to the training set the network will have no problem reconstructing the input and hence lower reconstruction loss. But I think the issue might be the lack of training data since I believe 1000 is small for your network to generalize the concept of a vehicle, but who knows if you dont try.

Answer (score 0):

Guess there's already `vehicle` label in ImageNet, so the easiest way would be not to train anything at all. You can also easily scrap both `vehicle` and `non-vehicle` images from the net. Check this [post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/12/04/how-to-create-a-deep-learning-dataset-using-google-images/). 1k images is a bit too little to train DNN. Feature space is hyper-dimensional, so you need something deeper, this means your net capacity will grow. Training with little data will result in overfit. Try also to augment your data set heavily. You can easily make it two orders of magnitude bigger.